# Alarm behaving very strangely

Tags: stock-android, alarm

*There is already another question like this ([Alarm is disabled when device is switched off](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210124/287520)) but my question is slightly different from those.*

In my new phone with *Android 7.0 Nougat*, I found something strange.
Suppose, I have set an alarm at 7:00 AM and at that time, the phone is switched off. I found that the alarm works absolutely fine - the screen turns on and the ringtone is played.
But, if the screen is not touched within about 15 seconds, such as, snoozing or dismissing the alarm, **the screen turns off permanently**, means that even if I hold down the power button, it doesn't turns on. But the ringtone continues to play.
Then I need to pull out the battery, reinsert it and again restart the phone.

Now I have somehow coped up with this issue by setting the *Automatic power on time* to two minutes before the alarm, that is, at 6:58 AM. But, that is not the solution, because I may sometimes set the alarm to before the power on time and I may forget to change the power on time. I am really fed up with this problem.

Why does this happens and how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Seems like an issue with the device's firnware/configuration. This should mostly be handled by the OEM. Can you check that you have all OS updates installed?

Comment: Do you mean OTA updates? No, my device has still not received any OS updates.

Comment: That's sad. You can check the phone manufacturer's website if any offline packages are available to update your smartphone.

Comment: Is there any root-related method to fix the issue? Because I don't think it can be solved without rooting.

Comment: Kindly mention rest of the device details. Also check out forums for your device on XDA, or you can download fastboot rom (stock) from OEM's website and try flashing it. This might possibly fix the issue

Comment: My device is **Micromax Bharat 3 Q437** with Android 7.0 Nougat (stock ROM). MediaTek quad-core 1.09 GHz CPU.